# Removing unanswered questions

Tags: feature-request

Often, we come across questions that do not have answers or more than a few comments for the question. Sometimes it seems like they are abandoned even by the user who asked the question. So in those circumstances can we not delete the questions and make the website look less cluttered?

Is it being taken care of or am I being naive?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is automatic deletion in place for number of situations, see:

[How does deleting work? What can cause a post to be deleted, and what does that actually mean? What are the criteria for deletion?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5221/how-does-deleting-work-what-can-cause-a-post-to-be-deleted-and-what-does-that)

Comment: That was helpful. Thank you Rarst.